# 3D Rotation Using Fixed Point Arithmetic - Rotating Object is Deforming (and Shrinking)

Tags: fpga, verilog, gpu, 3d

I have an FPGA board (Virtex 5) for which I have created a Wireframe GPU with the ability to rotate a sample object using a 3 Axis Trackball.  Additionally, I have connected the board to a PC Monitor.

Initially the object can be seen intact (with no deformations)?  However, when I begin to move the trackball I notice the object begins to deform and shrink.

I have tried various methods to provide immunity to the problem but can not keep the object from deforming.

Primarily, I have tried to to multiply each coordinate by a correction factor on rotation so that as the points shrink I multiply by the correction factor (determined by the original distance to the center for each point divided by the new shrunk distance).

With these methods in place I still am unable to prevent the deformation.

Is there any way in fixed-point to keep the object coordinates intact on rotation?

Comment: Rotate from the initial orientation so that you don't lose precision unnecessarily.

Comment: I was under the impression  that rotation is 3D is not commutative.  I was trying to store successive rotations in a rotation buffer to preserve the previous state.  Would this prevent me from rotating from the initial orientation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rotating a virtual 3 dimensional object rather than a question relating to electrical/electronic engineering

Comment: I will try to direct the question to the appropriate place.  Thank you.

Comment: It is on topic as it is about digital hardware design

Comment: How many bits in: operands, result (accumulator), extension bits? Signed?

Comment: If I understand correctly:  X, Y, Z are each [2:-11]. MSB for each is the sign bit.  Total bits per axis (x,y,z) is 14 each.  I also use the same number of bits after rotation.  Would I need to provide any additional parameters?

Comment: One other note, I am using a Sin/Cos ROM with 1024 addresses producing values of sin[1:-14] and cos[1:-14].   Bit 1 is the sign bit and bit 0 is the magnitude which is either 1 or 0.   The sin/cos values are multiplied by the coordinates using 3D rotation equations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that you know the problem, you can formulate a solution.

Fixed point arithmetic is inaccurate. So is floating point, so that does not generally solve the problem, merely defer it. (In some respects strict IEE P754 is an exception to this in that certain properties of operations are guaranteed, but that's not a complete solution : read some of Professor Kahan's work for more...)

It sounds as though you are iteratively computing each frame from the previous frame, so that rounding errors are accumulating. Further, if the object is consistently shrinking, it suggests you are truncating rather than rounding.

Some common techniques may help here:

(1) Truncation rather than rounding introduces a systematic error tending towards 0. You can solve this by rounding properly anywhere you would truncate (narrow a wide result to fit a narrow word)

Example:

```
signal A,B,C   : unsigned(15 downto 0);
signal Product : unsigned(31 downto 0);
...
Product <= A * B;
C <= Product(31 downto 16);
```

You have thrown away bits 15 downto 0, or on average 0.5LSBs of output C. A correctly rounded calculation would use this information (or at least its LSB) to give either `Product(31 downto 16)` or `Product(31 downto 16) + 1`.

For example

```
C <= Product(31 downto 16) + Product(15 downto 15);
```

The maximum error in each operation is thereby halved, and distributed either side of 0. However this may still leave the object randomly distorting, though random growth or shrinkage should average out.

(2) Use transformations known to preserve invariants. For example, instead of calculating X,Y,Z iteratively from the previous step, calculate X and Y iteratively, and Z from the equation `R^2 = X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2`, as `Z=sqrt(R^2 - X^2 - Y^2)` so that errors in X and Y may introduce small errors in Z, but the invariant (R) is guaranteed correct - thus preserving the size of the object.

(3) Expanding on Ignacio's useful comment:

Keep the sample object intact.

Track the rotation of a simple unit vector instead (length 1, any orientation) and having computed that for the current step (preserving its invariant i.e. R=1 as in step 2) rotate the original object by that unit vector. This guarantees that any errors do not persist beyond the current frame.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response. Let me see if I can come up with a solution based on this and I will reply back.

Comment: On point number 2 in your reply.  I actually used the distance formula to the center based on the original configuration to formulate my correction factor.  Let me try the suggestion.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: I am getting strange results when I try to adjust not only for Z but also for X and Y.  Are the X, Y adjustments unnecessary?  What I mean is instead of only solving for Z, I also solve for X and Y in parallel.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Your comment is unclear to me, but if you are not generating a triple (X,Y,Z) such that `X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = exactly 1` regardless of rounding errors then you will have a problem.

Comment: What I meant was do I have to apply the same sqrt formula for X and Y as well?

Comment: I suggested the sqrt formula for any one of the three, not all of them. I arbitrarily picked Z as an example, there is nothing special about that choice.

Comment: After my initial tries at debugging and implementing the invariant solution I gave up until recently when I retried this method.  It turns out I had to fix and uncover many timing issues (I spent three weeks but got better results).  By combining the invariant solution with the rounding solution I nearly got my answer.  The object still shrinks but at a much more uniform and even rate and much slower.  I will attempt to counter this by multiplying the distance by a slightly larger value than 1.0 times the original distance.  Perhaps that will grow the object, and hopefully preserve rigidity.